# java Convert lambda expression predicate to method reference?. Predicate<String> endsWith= str-> str.endsWith("a");

Tags: java, java-8

Please let me know. I was reading method reference it was mentioned that an alternative way of a lambda expression and shown some examples but when I tried to do convert my own predicate to method reference I  could not able to do it.

```
Predicate<String> endsWith= str-> str.endsWith("a");
endsWith.test("asap");
```

returns the value.

How to convert the same as method reference ??

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can only use method reference in case:

- method have exactly one parameter

`Predicate endsWith = foo::endsWith;//foo is some variable`

`Predicate endsWith = FooClass::endsWith;//for static methods`

- method doesn't have parameters

`Predicate endsWith = FooClass::endsWith;//this method is not static`

Comment: @BoristheSpider You are right. Will fix it.

Comment: Your answer is very specific to the question’s `Predicate` use case. A method reference can have an arbitrary number of parameters, as long as it matches the function signature determined by the target interface. Or one less, for non-`static` methods when the receiver becomes an implicit parameter.